# Visual Studio Paste XML as Classes - Ignores Type Name

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

So I am using Visual Studio 16.8.4.

I have a XML file that I am trying to convert to code. the object Type names are defined as `i:Type="someclass"` but I am not ending up with that being the class name.

EIA:
My specific question is, is there a better tool to use that will not ignore the types? Is there an easy way I can modify the XML so that VS will not ignore the types?
/EIA:

Here is a small snippet, that I confirmed produces the same issue as the larger file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Screen xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">    
        <Object i:type="AlarmControlType">
        <blahblah></blahblah>
        </Object>
</Screen>
```

What I expect from this is

```
public class Screen
{
    public AlarmControlType Object {get; set;}
}

public class AlarmControlType 
{
    public string blahblah {get;set;} 

}
```

What I get is

```
// NOTE: Generated code may require at least .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core/Standard 2.0.
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Screen
{

    private ScreenObject objectField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public ScreenObject Object
    {
        get
        {
            return this.objectField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.objectField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ScreenObject
{

    private object blahblahField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public object blahblah
    {
        get
        {
            return this.blahblahField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.blahblahField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question, though? This post reads more like a feature-request for VS's dev team than anything we can help you with.

Comment: I agree the generated code isn't as a minimal as it could be, but mapping XML elements (from XSD) to C# classes is actually a _really hard_ problem. For example, XML element names can contain characters that C# classes can't, e.g. `<foo-bar>` is valid XML, and without an XSD the code-gen has no idea how the different elements relate to each other.

Comment: ...and do you have an XSD? If not, then you're asking for trouble, tbh.

Comment: Fair: Point I updated my question To contain a specific question.

And no I do not have an XSD I am trying to reverse engineer my classes from an XML file alone.

Comment: Your XML is not usable as-is: you have `i:type="AlarmControlType` but without an XSD that defines _exactly what_ "AlarmControlType" actually is VS - or any other tool - can't do anything useful.

Comment: "And no I do not have an XSD I am trying to reverse engineer my classes from an XML file alone" - then you're working a fool's errand. Except for only the most trivial cases you cannot automate application code-gen from a single XML file. **you need the XSD**. That said, XSD is simple to write, why not just write one yourself?

Comment: Well because I didn't even know what an XSD was until I googled it 5 minutes ago LOL.